# convert string to dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to convert A string into a dictionary using pairSeparator and keyValueSeparator.
how i will define this:

```
def stringToDictionary(s, pairSeparator, keyValueSeparator):

 ....
 ....

 return D
```

I WANT THIS RESULT:

```
s = 'potatoes:2.67,sugar:1.98,cereal:5.99,crisps:1.09'    
D = stringToDictionary(s, ',', ':')
print(D)
{'sugar': 1.98, 'cereal': 5.99, 'potatoes': 2.67, 'crisps': 1.09}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary

Comment: @xFortyFourx But here the string is not a string representation of dict.

Answer (score 1):

## Split!

Pretty simple to solve just by using splits. You might want to add some error checking, but basically do something like this:

```
def stringToDictionary(s, pairSeparator, keyValueSeparator):
    pairs = s.split(pairSeparator)
    return dict(pair.split(keyValueSeparator) for pair in pairs)
```

I notice that in your expected output you convert the values to integers. To keep this function general I'd recommend either allowing passing a converter function in to stringToDictionary or simply to convert the values afterwards.

Comment: thank you so much :) i was doing the same thing but i had wrong in last sentence! thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loop. If your string strictly follows the format you provided, then this.

```
def stringToDictionary(s, pairSeparator, keyValueSeparator):
    items = s.split(pairSeparator)
    data = {}
    for item in items:
        keyvalpair = item.split(keyValueSeparator)
        data[keyvalpair[0].strip()] = float(keyvalpair[1]) # strip() removes unwanted trailing/leading spaces

    return data

print stringToDictionary("potatoes:2.67,sugar:1.98,cereal:5.99,crisps:1.09", ',', ':')
```

EDIT: It's made into a function like you asked.

Answer (score 0):

can you build same logic for your custom function as ,

```
>>> s = 'potatoes:2.67,sugar:1.98,cereal:5.99,crisps:1.09'.split(",")
>>> d={}
>>> for i in s:
    d[i.split(':')[0]]=float(i.split(':')[1])


>>> d
{'potatoes': '2.67', 'crisps': '1.09', 'cereal': '5.99', 'sugar': '1.98'}
>>>
```